# Free comment system

Tags: gratis, chat, web-services, react, comment-system

I have built an app and want to implement a comment service.

Now my app is very simple and has no data storage server so I cant have those comment saved on my end.

What I want is a free chat service that don't require the user to login, the user should simple comment on the product I have in the app without login.

I want something similar to https://disqus.com but without login service, and that also can be installed without having any website.